# Scanner.nextLine() throws an Exception, if I close the first Scanner and create a new Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I want to implement a programm, which reads two strings from the user input.

```
        try 
    {
        System.out.println( "please enter a valid URL ( i.e. http://www.uibk.ac.at )" );
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        String urlString = inputScanner.next(); 
        asciiTable = new int[NUM_ASCII_CHAR];
        URL url = new URL( urlString );
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() );
        countCharactersfromFile( in );
        printAsciiTable( asciiTable );
        printNumberOfChars( asciiTable );
        inputScanner.close();
        in.close();
    }
    // it has not the form of an URL
    catch ( MalformedURLException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // If the site cannot be connected
    catch( UnknownHostException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // some IO-Error occurs
    catch ( IOException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // if the ASCII array is empty
    catch( EmptyListException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        System.out.println( "Please enter the name of a file " );
        asciiTable = new int[NUM_ASCII_CHAR];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        String fileString = scanner.next();
        FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream( fileString );
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader( fileStream );
        countCharactersfromFile( in );
        printAsciiTable( asciiTable );
        printNumberOfChars( asciiTable );
        scanner.close();        
    }
    catch ( IOException e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( EmptyListException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At first I want to let you know that I know the problem. I should only use 1 Scanner in my program. But if use only one **try block** in my program, i am not allowed to execute the 2nd part of the task, if an exception is thrown.
I have a solution, but I do not know if it is a good one.

```
try
{
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    try
    {
        //the URL code, use inputScanner here
    }
    catch()
    {

    }
    try
    {
        // The file code, use inputscanner here
    }
    catch()
    {

    }
    inputscanner.close();
}
catch()
```

Is the solution, which is shown above a good one? Or do you have some better solutions for my problem.

Thanks
Patrik

Comment: `scanner.close()` will close the standard `System.in` stream as well. close it in the end only.

Comment: Can't you just declare it outside of the `try` scopes?

Comment: your try catch blocks are so cumbersome. why don't you use try catch block with resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure `Scanner` is always closed, wrap all code using it into a `try` block and close it in `finally` block afterwards:

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    try {
        // 1st operation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("1st operation failed");
    }
    try {
        // 2nd operation
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("2nd operation failed");
    }
} finally {
    inputScanner.close();
}
```

Or use try-with-resource, which will do the same:

```
try (Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    ...
}
```

It might be better not to close `inputScanner` at all. You will not be able to read anything else from standard input. Scanner doesn't consume any additional system resources so you can let garbage collector worry about it.

Additional tip: Do not catch exceptions, if you are not doing anything useful with them. Just let them propagate. You can even declare `main` method to throw an `Exception`.